# HTTP PATCH - RFC 6902- JAVA Json library

Tags: java, json, http, patch, rfc

I'm trying to use the HTTP PATCH method based on [RFC 6902](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902). Is there any good JAVA library that can use this perform these operations (add, remove, replace) described in this chapter [PATCH Operations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#section-4)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found two libraries:

- [zjsonpatch](https://github.com/flipkart-incubator/zjsonpatch)
- [json-patch](https://github.com/fge/json-patch)

Comment: We use zjsonpatch in production and are generally quite happy.